# Parity POA Smart Contract Method Always Fails

Tags: solidity, remix, private-blockchain, parity, poa

I have set up a private POA Network according to the [tutorial](https://wiki.parity.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial) from the parity homepage. I have two nodes running on localhost:8540 and localhost:8541. I have connected MetaMask to my first node and am able to send transactions between test accounts and even deploy a smart contract from remix. Unfortunately I am not able to call the functions from the deployed contract as the gas estimation always fails and the transaction gets mined but execution fails.

Here are my configurations:

Spec.json

```
{
"name": "OraclePOA",
"engine": {
    "authorityRound": {
        "params": {
            "stepDuration": "5",
            "validators" : {
                "list": [
                    "0x0038ba71301213d9508ce44fd25272d83b1c5dae",
                    "0x002e9ac8fef5ab0d0591488860562438ab154bd4"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"params": {
    "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
    "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
    "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
    "networkID" : "0x2323",
    "maxCodeSize": "0x6000",
    "eip155Transition": 0,
    "validateChainIdTransition": 0,
    "eip140Transition": 0,
    "eip211Transition": 0,
    "eip214Transition": 0,
    "eip658Transition": 0
},
"genesis": {
    "seal": {
        "authorityRound": {
            "step": "0x0",
            "signature": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    },
    "difficulty": "0x100000",
    "gasLimit": "0x1000000"
},
"accounts": {
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ecrecover", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } } },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "sha256", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } } },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ripemd160", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } } },
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "identity", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } } },
    "0x00d695cd9b0ff4edc8ce55b493aec495b597e235": { "balance": "10000000000000000000000" },
    "0x001ca0bb54fcc1d736ccd820f14316dedaafd772": { "balance": "10000000000000000000000" }
}
}
```

The configuration of the node connected to MetaMask:

```
[parity]
chain = "oracle-spec.json"
base_path = "/myOracle/parity0"
[network]
port = 30300
[rpc]
port = 8540
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[websockets]
port = 8450
[account]
password = ["authNode0.pwds"]
[mining]
engine_signer = "0x0038ba71301213d9508ce44fd25272d83b1c5dae"
reseal_on_txs = "none"
usd_per_tx = "0"
```

here is my sample contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.7;
contract Sample{
    //address of owner
    address payable owner;

    //whoever deploys contract is the owner
   constructor() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
   }

    function doSomething() external payable {
        int i = 10 + 10;
        i++;
   }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the Transaction via Remix]

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was the compiler version of solidity. The smart contract only works with a solidity version below 0.5.4. There is already a Ticket in Github. For more information check: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/10502